# 'require relative' error on rails -v

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to install Ruby on Rails but every time I get the following error. For example I check for the version of rails and this comes out:

```
Jacks-MacBook-Air:~ jackscotti$ rails -v
bin/rails:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /Users/jackscotti/config/boot (LoadError)
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

This is how I have installed it. I am following the instructions from the book "Agile Web Development with Rails 4".
Here it is:

```
$curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable 
$rvm install 2.0.0 --autolibs=enable
$rvm use 2.0.0
$gem install rails --version 4.0.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc
$rvm --default 2.0.0
```

and then i get the error when i type:

```
$rails-v
```

** LOCAL GEMS **

```
actionmailer (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
actionpack (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
activemodel (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
activerecord (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activesupport (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
arel (4.0.1)
atomic (1.1.14)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.1.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.2.6)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.5)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.8.2)
polyglot (0.3.3)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
railties (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rubygems-update (2.1.9)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sprockets (2.10.1)
sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.38)
```

Comment: `require_relative` is a Ruby 1.9.x method. What version of Ruby do you run? Call `ruby -v`

Comment: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]

Comment: Can you please post the content of the following files: `bin/rails` (where the error occurs in line 3) and `config/boot.rb` (the file that is usually loaded in line 3 in `bin/rails`).

Comment: **Jacks-MacBook-Air:~ jackscotti$ bin/rails** I GET THE SAME MESSAGE:


bin/rails:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /Users/jackscotti/config/boot (LoadError)
 from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Comment: Open it in an editor...

Comment: opened, that's what i get: 
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'

Comment: Okay, looks like the default. Please open also the file `config/boot.rb`. Does it exist?

Comment: this is the content:

# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])

Comment: Do you have the `bundler` gem installed?

Comment: I guess so, I followed many tutorials and I installed everything. How do I check it?

Comment: I am going to type everything I have written on the terminal, on the body of the question. Give me a sec. :)

Comment: Check with `gem list` if you have `bundler` installed. Where did you rails app come from? Did you generate it or did you clone some repo?

Comment: I wrote all the gems in the body of the question. Rails comes from:
    $gem install rails --version 4.0.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc